# Named tuple as parameter type hints

Tags: python

How do I properly document a named tuple as a function parameter with type hints? In PyCharm it gives an unresolved reference warning when accessing the tuple items by their names.

Answer (score 2):

First, there's a syntax problem.

You need to reference a variable name:

```py
# ... my_function(Tuple[str, str]) is invalid code.
# Take a look at the references to see how to use type annotations.
def my_function(variable_name: Tuple[str, str])
```

Second, you're creating the type definition within a method and not exposing that type anywhere.

You need to refactor the code so `Header` can be accessed globally.

E.g.

```py
Header = namedtuple(
    "Header",
    [
        "resource_type",
        "serialization_method",
        "head_revision",
        "dependency_table_offset",
        "branch_id",
        "branch_revision",
        "compression_flags",
        "is_compressed",
    ],
)

# Other module level namespaces.
class Random:
  pass

def random_function:
  pass
```

In other words, the type should be located outside any class or function and should be found in the module scope (in your case, it's likely going to be at the same level of the class).

Third, reference the named tuple.

So, if your named tuple is something along the lines of:

For `python 3.6+`

```py
class Header(NamedTuple):
  first_val: int
  second_val: int
```

Or, alternatively for `python 3.1+`:

```py
Header = namedtuple('Header', ['first_val', 'second_val'])
```

Then, your function signature would be updated to reference the `Header`. E.g.

```py
def my_function(tuple: Header) -> None:
  pass
```

References:

- [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)
- [`NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple)
- [`Type Annotations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)

Comment: The named tuple isn't it's own class. It looks something like: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/namedtuple-in-python/, and the named tuple is a property of an entire class that has all of its own logic.

Comment: @6x2KYqRT yes it is, reference https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple

Comment: And the tuple it takes as a parameter could reference any instance from that class.

Comment: @6x2KYqRT I should clarify that both can be used. You could alternatively use the `namedtuple` factory, however, the logic remains the same, you need to reference the generated class.

Comment: @6x2KYqRT `And the tuple it takes as a parameter could reference any instance from that class.` Can you clarify, please? What do you mean it can reference any instance? It's a type annotation, not a singleton.

Comment: I still don't get it. I updated my question to include the actual named tuple. Can you show what it would look like please?

Comment: @6x2KYqRT I've updated my answer. For future reference, please don't delete parts of your question, it makes tracking the conversations difficult.

Comment: I'm still confused. The named tuple is a property of a class that's a separate module. I can't just "refactor" the code easily. All of the attribute of the named tuple are set inside the external class and are returned as a named tuple via the property method.

Comment: I just copied and pasted your answer in PyCharm, and it still says unresolved reference, so it's not even that I have a different problem anyway.

Comment: @6x2KYqRT It's the same problem. You can and you should be able to refactor the code easily. The `Header` tuple is a namespace, you can just move it outside the class and invoke it in other places. I think you need to first understand the difference between an instance and the class definition. You need to have the definition in the module scope, instances can be placed in any scope.